# sql statement for inserting data in database for current month to next 2 months

Tags: ios, sqlite

How to insert bulk data in `SQLite` database from current month to next 2 month.

I want to insert current month data into `SQLite` with all `values (0,0,0)(?,?,?)` ;

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@(\"month\", \"date\", \"time\") Values(?, ?, ?)",tableName];
```

I want to insert from current month start date to next coming 3 months data into timesheetTable.

Comment: From which table you want to insert data?

Comment: timesheetTable i want to insert

Comment: kkMIW check my answer.It works perfectly for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert data from another table you can try like this

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@(month,date,time) Values (SELECT month,date,time FROM timesheetTable WHERE dateFieldName between date('now','start of month') and date('now','start of month','+2 month')",tableName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@(month, date, time) Values('%@', '%@', '%@')",tableName,month,date,time];
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the sample one for you and I got the solution. From Current Date to Next Two months

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSInteger yearCurrent = [gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"The year is: %ld", yearCurrent);

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *compo = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger month = compo.month;
NSLog(@"The month is: %ld", month);

NSDateComponents *compDay = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger dateDay = compDay.day;
NSLog(@"The dateDay is: %ld",dateDay);


NSDate *firstDateOfMonth = [self getDateOfMonth:yearCurrent :month :dateDay];
NSDate *firstDateOfNextTwoMonth = [self getDateOfMonth:yearCurrent :month + 2 :dateDay];
NSDateComponents *component = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:firstDateOfMonth toDate:firstDateOfNextTwoMonth options:0];
NSInteger totalDays = [component day];
NSLog(@"The total days are %ld", totalDays);


- (NSDate *)getDateOfMonth:(NSInteger)year:(NSInteger)month :(NSInteger)day
{
  NSDateComponents *dc = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
  dc.year = year;
  dc.month = month;
  dc.day = day;
  return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dc];
}
```

The Printed results are

```
The year is: 2016
The month is: 8
The dateDay is: 9
```

Finally  total days are

```
The total days are 61
```

Now you ot total number of days, so in for loop set the

```
for(int i=0;i<totalDays;i++)
{
    //Do your stuff here......
    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@(month, date, time) Values(?, ?, ?)",tableName];
    sqlite3_stmt *stment=nil;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[strQuery UTF8String] , -1, &stment, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
       sqlite3_bind_text(stment, 1, [strMonth UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
       sqlite3_bind_text(stment, 1, [strDate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
       sqlite3_bind_text(stment, 1, [strTime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
       sqlite3_step(stment);
       sqlite3_reset(stment);
    }        
}
```